# Getting Flex TileList image source

Tags: apache-flex, drag-and-drop, tilelist

I have a TileList that's loaded with data from Flickr.  The tilelist uses an imageRenderer to make a bunch of thumbnails.

I'm trying to create a custom drag and drop function, but I want to get the image source of the tilelist mouseEvent target.  Here's what the code looks like for the drag handler:

```
public function onPicMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void {
            var tileList:TileList = TileList(e.currentTarget);

            var item:Object = Object(tileList.selectedItem);

            var source:DragSource = new DragSource();

            var dragView : Image = new Image();
            dragView.source = tileList.selectedItem.source;

            DragManager.doDrag(
                rowRenderer,
                source,
                e,
                dragView
              );
}
```

But tileList.selectedItem doesn't have a source property.  The source is a property of the image produced by the itemrenderer.   I'd like to be able to do something that's the equivalent of

```
tileList.selectedItem.itemRenderer.source
```

But that doesn't do it either.

There's got to be a simple way to do this that I'm just missing.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your onMousePicDown handler your source should be:

```
dragView.source = event.target.parent.source;
```